# Dialog box asking for number

Tags: java, swing, validation, dialog, event-handling

What is the best way to create a dialog box asking for number? And avoid situations when an user can enter a letter or leave the dialog box empty?
I wrote something like this but I think that it can be improved:

```
private int giveInt(String message)
{
    int result =0;
    boolean successful = false;
    String[] options = {"OK"};
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(message);
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
    panel.add(lbl);
    panel.add(txt);
    do{
        try {
            int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel,
                    "Enter number", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                    null, options , options[0]);
            if(selectedOption == 0)
            {
                String input= txt.getText();
                if(input!=null)
                {
                    result = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    successful = true;
                }
                else result=0;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter an number");
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter an number");
        }
    }while (!successful);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `What is the best way to create a dialog box asking for number? And avoid situations when an user can enter a letter or leave the dialog box empty?` == use JSpinner/JComboBox (with Numbers in Model) instead of